# How to download surge.sh repository?

Tags: download, repository, clone, recover, surge.sh

How to download surge.sh repository? I deployed application, then lost code. How to recover it from surge.sh? Github repository was not updated.

Until 2016, it was not possible: https://github.com/sintaxi/surge/issues/192

Answer (score 0):

Try scraping the website and downloading each file.
Or you could make a sitemap to your root directory. It helps SEO and also helps a lot to bots.

BTW thanks for the project idea, i can make a surge site downloader :D

you get the point. options are:

1. scrape the website
2. download each file yourself
3. make a bot (or find one) and download the site
4. use sitemap to download all files using a bot (or make one)

So key points are:

1. next time make sitemap
2. use git
3. push to github (if necessary)

Hope this helps!